# How to communicate from A to C via B (group owner) with WiFi Direct in Android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I want to connect 3 devices via WiFi Direct group. When device A and C connected to B (Group owner) how to exchange data between A and C. Does A see C in that case? Or A sees only B and I have to write logic on B like:

```
data from A to C

if (C.isConnected) {
    send data to C
}
```